# Typescript: Creating a coordinates type that takes in dimension as a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to define a few types that extend arrays with specific lengths. I have fixed length arrays and minimum length arrays:

```
interface FixedLengthArray<T, L extends number> extends ReadonlyArray<T> {
  0: T;
  length: L;
}
type Coordinates2D = FixedLengthArray<number, 2>;
type Coordinates3D = FixedLengthArray<number, 3>

type CoordinatesMin2D = {
  0: number
  1: number
} & ReadonlyArray<number>

type CoordinatesMin3D = {
  0: number
  1: number
  2: number
} & ReadonlyArray<number>

Coordinates = ReadonlyArray<number>;
```

I want to define an interface that takes in any of the above values, and functions that work with some but not necessarily all of those types:

```
interface KeyAndCoords {
  key: string;
  coordinates:  // one of the above types, not sure how to define this 
}

// not sure how to define the generics so that
// I can pass in a KeyAndCoords type of either Coordinates2D, Coordinates3D,
// CoordinatesMin2D, CoordinatesMin3D and **NOT** regular Coordinates
const center2DCoordinates = (keyAndCoords: KeyAndCoords[]): KeyAndCoords => {}
```

whats the right way to handle these generics?

ETA1: To clarify more, Coordinates could be an arbitrary sized list. I wouldn't want that value to be passed into `center2DCoordinates`, because it may not have 2 dimensions to work with. But if there was a function that just grabbed the max of the list, say `getMaxOfCoordinates`, that should work with all of the above listed types.

So the following should succeed/fail if passed into `center2DCoordinates`:

```
x: Coordinates = [1]  // fail
x: Coordinates = [1, 1]  // succeed
x: Coordinates = [1, 1, 1]  // succeed
x: Coordinates2D = [1, 1]  // succeed
x: Coordinates3D = [1, 1, 1]  // succeed
x: CoordinatesMin2D = [1, 1, 1]  // succeed

center2DCoordinates(x)
```

Comment: what do you mean with *"NOT regular Coordinates"*? Since `CoordinatesMin2D` allows arrays of any length at least longer than 1, that would only leave arrays of size 1 and 0 that should not be allowed? Could you clarify in the question how valid and how invalid calls to the function would look like?

Comment: Also, is there any reason for using these verbose types instead of just writing `type Coordinates2D = [number, number]`?

Comment: Haha, [number, number] would do fine. My understanding is that typescript handles tuple types differently from other types, which is why i was trying to have everything extend from ReadonlyArray.

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbBxom) fit your needs? If so, I could write an answer. Note that something typed as `Coordinates` will always lead to a compile time error when passed to the function. `Coordinates` is a super-type of all the other types and thus can't be assigned to them, no matter which value you actually assign to it.

Comment: I think it's close, thanks for this. A follow up question: is there a way to get the fixed/minimum length of the coordinates array out as a generic? I have some uses where I want to pass in an array of the same size, e.g.
`scale2DCoordinates = <Length>(arr: Coordinates<Length>, scales: FixedLengthArray<number, Length>)` -- is there a way to do this with both fixedlength and minimumlength types above?